# Quartz Scheduler V3 not firing on IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I have an ASP.Net MVC application (C#), when i run the project the job is working properly and on time , but after publish to server it's not working and not firing , The IIS version is 10.

The Job Scheduler :

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail jobInsertIntoKPIFollowupReadings = JobBuilder.Create<InsertIntoKPIFollowupReadings>().Build();
        ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.MonthlyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(1,0,0))
            .ForJob(jobInsertIntoKPIFollowupReadings).Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobInsertIntoKPIFollowupReadings, trigger1);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
The start in Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //Enabling Bundling and Minification
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

        JobScheduler.Start();

    }
```

Anyone could help ?

Comment: @Fildor yes, i just update the question.

Comment: Instead of a local var inside the `Start` method, have you tried to use a static field in `JobScheduler` for the `IScheduler` instance?

Comment: @Fildor Sorry, i don't get it, could you please tell me how apply this ? and is this a solution for the issue ?

Comment: I am suspecting a lifetime issue. I would try to keep the scheduler "alive" by saving a reference in a static field ( `private static IScheduler _scheduler;` ). But I am not 100% sure this will solve your issue. It is just a suspicion, hence only comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Fildor ok i will try it, thank you